# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null obj

Tags: visualforce

I have been building a VF page that updates child and parent records

The error that I get back after inputting is
​​​​​​
Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Error is in expression '{!insertChild}' in component
>    in page updatechild:
>   Class.AddingChildController.insertChild: line 23, column 1

[image: screenshot of error]

This is the VF page

```
    <apex:page controller="AddingChildController" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}" />
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!0}" />
        <apex:PageBlockTable value="{!childList}" var="int">
        <apex:facet name="footer">
            <apex:commandLink value="Add" action="{!insertRow}"/>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:column headerValue="Lead Generator">
                <apex:inputField value="{!int.Lead_Gen__c}"/>                                      
            </apex:column>



            <apex:column headerValue="Monday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Monday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Tuesday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Tuesday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Wednesday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Wednesday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Thursday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Thursday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Friday">
            <apex:inputField value="{!int.Friday__c}"/>
            </apex:column>
             <apex:column headerValue="Delete">
            <apex:commandLink style="font-size:15px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center;color:red;" value="X" action="{!delRow}">
                <apex:param value="{!rowNum}" name="index"/>
                </apex:commandLink>
                <apex:variable var="rowNum" value="{!rowNum+1}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:PageBlockTable>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!insertChild}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And this is the controller

```
public class AddingChildController {
Id parentId;
public List<Time_Sheets__c> childList {get;set;}
public Integer rowNum{get;set;}

public Lead_Gen__c Parent {get;set;}





public AddingChildController(){
    Id childId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('childId');
    childList = new List<Time_Sheets__c>();
    childList.add(new Time_Sheets__c());
    ParentId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ParentId');   

}

public pagereference insertChild(){
    insert childList;

    Parent.Id=parentId;
    update Parent;

    Pagereference page=new pagereference('/'+parentId);
    Return page;


}    

public void insertRow(){
    childList.add(new Time_Sheets__c());


}

public void delRow(){
    rowNum = 
Integer.valueof(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('index'));

childList.remove(rowNum);
}
}
```

Any ideas where im going wrong with the insert child on save button ?

Cheers

Comment: Do you know what the error message is telling you?

Comment: What are you trying to update in parent object i.e. what is `update Parent` line updating ? You are getting that error because you have not initialized `Parent` object.

Comment: The parent gets updated via a lookup (required field) on the page, What I am trying to do (unsuccessfully) is then display the recently updated records (including the parents look up field ) on to my follow up page, So its with the follow up page i require the assistance with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but as far as I am understanding, you want to redirect to the parent's detail page after inserting the child records.

If that's the case, then you can simply do

```
public pagereference insertChild(){
    insert childList;

    Pagereference parentPage;
    if(!childList.isEmpty() && !string.isBlank(childList[0].Lead_Gen__c))
        parentPage=new pagereference('/'+childList[0].Lead_Gen__c);
    return parentPage;
}
```

So here it is redirecting to the first child record's parents detail page assuming that all child records have the same parent record.

Comment: thanks for this  but I got a compile error saying  Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: page at line 26 column 12 which is pointing to return page;

Comment: That was a typo, fixed it

Comment: thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve this error by initializing the parent obj like:

Instead of this line

```
Parent.Id=parentId;
```

you have to initialize Parent:

```
Parent = new Lead_Gen__c ();
Parent.Id=parentId;
```

But didn't understand what you are trying to achieve here by updating parent. Since you are not passing any parent field values...

Comment: I was only doing that to render the record that should get saved upon Now I am getting this  Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call: []
Error is in expression '{!insertChild}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page updatechild: Class.AddingChildController.insertChild: line 19, column 1

Class.AddingChildController.insertChild: line 19, column 1

Comment: I only added Parent.Id=parentId;
    update Parent;  because with out it I was gettingURL No Longer Exists
You have attempted to reach a URL that no longer exists on salesforce.com.